# How to inherit fields in android xml?

Tags: android

I want to set some properties for the first `ImageView` element, and then inherit the properties in other elements.

The following does not work, but probably there is something similar?

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myimage"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="100dp"/>

<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myimage2"
            android:layout_height="@myimage/layout_height"
            android:layout_width="@myimage/layout_width"/>
```

Comment: you will have to create a resource in `dimens.xml` which will come under `res>values` and use that for whichever xml element you want

Comment: So I cannot make cross references inside the same file?

Comment: You can make style for it.

Comment: You could use a dimension e.g. in res/values/dimens.xml add `<dimen name="myimageheight">100dp</dimen>` along with `android:layout_height="@dimens/myimageheight"` (repeat this where needed).

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this? If it is for reusability, take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension).

Comment: I want to set an invisible 2nd imageview overlay on the first, and show it programatically. Therefore it must be for example of the same size as the underlying element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that in that way, but you have 2 options here:

**Option 1**: declare the value as a dimension and the use it:

Declare two values for height and width in `dimens.xml` that can be found at `res/values`.

```
<dimen name="image_width">100dp</dimen>
<dimen name="image_height">100dp</dimen>
```

Then use them in your xml like this:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myimage2"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_height"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/image_width"/>
```

**Option 2**: Create a `style` associated with your `ImageView`:

First thing to do is to create the style for your views and place it in `styles.xml` that can be found at `res/values`.

```
<style name="my_image_view_style">
    <item name="android:layout_height">100dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">100dp</item>
</style>
```

Add your created `style` to your `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myimage2"
        style="@style/my_image_view_style"/>
```

Comment: `<style>` looks promising. But trying to use it states "attribute is missing the android namespace". Where do I have to put those styles? In the same file, or in a different one?

Comment: You need to declare the in the `styles.xml` file in `resources`. I'll edit my answer to make it easier to understand.